# How to add utility panel in tabulator?

Tags: c#, jquery, tabulator

I would like to add utility panel(Consist of Delete and Edit) for each row in tabulator.

It looks like this [image: Utility Panel] at ui. Delete and Edit button will appear upon click on [image: Utility Panel]

I found codes below which will create delete button for each row but that's not something I want

```
{formatter:"buttonCross", width:40, align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell){
    cell.getRow().delete();
}},
```

Delete and Edit option is available upon click on utility panel

[image: Utility Panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out bootstrap have utility panel feature which you can download it.

Use that css when generate column and row in tabulator.